# How to generate maven jar that will include my external jars that under lib folder

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have maven project with lib folder that contains some jars,
In my pom.xml, I've added dependency accordingly like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>autoit</groupId>
    <artifactId>autoit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/AutoItX4Java.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

The problem is when I create a jar and run on `cmd` I get Exception:

> nested exception is:      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError :
>   AutoItX4Java...

If I run via eclipse there are no Errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: 1. What command are you using on cmd?  2. Please share your complete stack trace and possible class structure in your project.

Comment: mvn assembly:single - creates jar

Comment: when i run the jar , my main is running. but when we reach to code that use my jar that under lib (AutoItX4Java.jar) , i get exception: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: autoitx4java/AutoItX